# Communication from Extension to PWA in Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to send a URL from my Edge Extension to Windows Progressive Web App. I can't seem to find a way to establish this connection.

It seems edge doesn't support sendMessage to other extensions or apps.

Comment: MS Edge supports Native messaging to communicate with UWP apps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging But I did not get any way to communicate with PWA from Edge extension. So it looks like this functionality is not available currently.

Comment: True that, I am trying now with UWP instead of PWA. Edge has a long way to go.

Comment: "The Microsoft Edge extension platform restricts the native messaging host to being a UWP app that is packaged in the same AppX as the extension" 
Looks like it is UWP only.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I definitely could, But I don't think there could be any relevance to the question with that. Its more of "someone must know how to do this".

Comment: At present, Functionality to communicate between PWA and Edge extension is not available. I already submit the feedback to Microsoft developers regarding this request. Thanks for your understanding.